# How to draw a line between several std::vectors of points in modern opengl

Tags: c++, opengl, vector, opengl-3

```
    ...   

    glBindVertexArray(LineVertexArrayObject);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(vertexPosition);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, LineVertexBufferObject);

    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER,sizeof(GLfloat)*vector_of_points.size(), &vector_of_points[0] ,GL_DYNAMIC_DRAW);

    glVertexAttribPointer(
        vertexPosition,
        2,
        GL_FLOAT,
        GL_FALSE,
        2*sizeof(GLfloat),
        (GLvoid*)0
    );

    glDrawArrays(GL_LINES,0,NUMBER_OF_LINES);

    glDisableVertexAttribArray(AttributeColor);
    glDisableVertexAttribArray(vertexPosition);
    glBindVertexArray(0);

    ...
```

The code above is drawing lines in one std::vector, but as the title goes, how can I draw a line between two or several different std::vectors of points in the 2D space, for example if I want to draw a [parallel coordinate](https://www.google.se/search?q=parallel%20coordinates&client=ubuntu&hs=JNZ&channel=fs&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwizj7_Zgd7MAhUsG5oKHYwMDSsQ_AUIBygB&biw=1639&bih=958) with each axis as a std::vector?

Comment: I'm a bit confused, thanks to C++'s ridiculous naming of its dynamic array class. It's not clear when you mean "vector" as in a 3D direction/position, and when you mean `std::vector` the C++ template class. If all of your uses of the word "vector" are referring to the class, why not put all of your line data in a single `std::vector`?

Comment: Thank you for the clarification, Yes I do mean std::vector, sorry for that. At the moment I do have everything in one vector, but I need to changed into different vectors (Each parallel coordinates axis get one vector) to make the rendering order correct.